# Tab disappears when changing language in iOS

Tags: ios, storyboard, uitabbar

One of the tabs in my UITabBar disappears when I change the language of my iOS Simulator to Norwegian. Why is this? I have created the app with Version 4.6.3 of XCode.

Comment: Screenshot? Are the other tabs getting too wide to be displayed?

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/EZGJs  Only one tab does disappear..

Comment: How are you specifying the order of the tabs? Are the missin ones in more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem.

When I tried to get my app translated I added my own languange in the Localizations section under Project-Info.

When I did this there was an extra .storyboard file created for the spesific language, so when I change the storyboard I had in xCode that did not change the second storyboard created for my language. I found my second storyboard in the directory of my app, and deleted it, and now everything works fine.

So, if your app is weird with one spesific language, it may have a spesific storyboard that does not change automatic.

Answer (score 0):

There could be a lot of reasons for this. You need to provide more information. How do you define your UITabBar? Are you using Storyboards or Nibs? Your Norwegian localized Storyboard / Nib might have only 1 tab defined while your English version might have three tabs.

Comment: This belongs in a comment, rather than an answer.

Comment: I have only used Storyboard. 

http://imgur.com/a/EZGJs

This is a link to a folder on imgur showing the same "more"-tab only in norwegian and english. The translation works fine, but one of the tabs("Teknologi") is missing in the translated version. And I have testet, it is only like this when I translate to Norwegian, not any other language...